# How to increase step progress bar in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

**Table where my data will be displayed-**

```
<table class="table" align="center">            
<tr>
<td>Job Code</td>
<td><b><?php echo ' ' . $dataProvider->models[0]->job_code; ?></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Client Code</td>
<td><b><?php echo ' ' . $dataProvider->models[0]->client_code; ?></b></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td>Status</td>
<td ><b><span name="current" data-value="CDP"><?php echo ' ' . $dataProvider->models[0]->status; ?></b></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**JS -**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var i = 1;
$('.progress .circle').removeClass().addClass('circle');
$('.progress .bar').removeClass().addClass('bar');
setInterval(function() {
$('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + i + ')').addClass('active');

$('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + (i - 1) + ')').removeClass('active').addClass('done');

$('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + (i - 1) + ') .label').html('&#10003;');

$('.progress .bar:nth-of-type(' + (i - 1) + ')').addClass('active');

$('.progress .bar:nth-of-type(' + (i - 2) + ')').removeClass('active').addClass('done');

i++;

if (i == 0) {
$('.progress .bar').removeClass().addClass('bar');
$('.progress div.circle').removeClass().addClass('circle');
i = 1;
}
}, 1000);
});
```

I have given table field an name, I want to progress this bar like-

```
if(status=approved)
{
  progress up to one step
}
elseif(status==digital)
{
progress up to Digital
}
elseif(status==CDP)
{
progress up to CDP
}
elseif(status==Printing)
{
progress up to Printing
}
and so on...
```

script should get value from table field and progress and step bar up to appropriate status. How to achieve this ?

CodePen Link- 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPBmXZ

Comment: I wonder how could you write just a little information but filled with codes? The website doesn't allow me to do that.

Comment: @Saurabh you have to make an online demo what you have tried so far. So that 1 can try to play with your code to make it work.

Comment: @RohanKumar updated the question with codepen link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.progress .circle').removeClass().addClass('circle');
    $('.progress .bar').removeClass().addClass('bar');
    $(".circle").first().addClass("active");

    var timer = setInterval(increment, 1000);

    function increment() {
        $(".circle:not(.done)").first().removeClass("active").addClass("done").children(":first-child").html("&#10003;");
        $(".circle:not(.done)").first().addClass("active");
        $(".circle.done").next().addClass("done");
        if ($(".active").find(".title").text() == $("tr:last-child").find("span").text()) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo of your code](https://jsfiddle.net/e9zL7sae/1/)

Comment: its not working on my page, `<td ><b><span name="current" data-value="CDP"><?php echo ' ' . $dataProvider->models[0]->status; ?></b></td>` as you can see data field will get value from database. its not working when I put php code, but if I put only status in data field it is working

Comment: `<span name="current" class="label label-success" data-value="<?php echo '' . $dataProvider->models[0]->status; ?>"><?php echo ' ' . $dataProvider->models[0]->status; ?></span>` - this is not working but this is working -  `<span name="current" class="label label-success" data-value="CDP">CDP</span>`

Comment: I suspect it might be spaces (that need to be trimmed) that are causing this issue. Can you quote the exact text that is echoed between the _span_ tag?

Comment: `<td><span name="current" class="label label-success" data-value="<?php echo ' ' . $dataProvider->models[0]->status; ?>"><b><?php echo ' ' . $dataProvider->models[0]->status; ?><b></span></td>`

Comment: I meant the resulting html that code on your page after the PHP code has been executed. `<td><span name="current" class="label label-success" data-value="[what is here?]"><b>[and what is here?]<b></span></td>`

Comment: ` <tr>
      <td>Status</td>
      <td><span name="current" class="label label-success" data-value=" CDP"><b>CDP<b></span></td>
     </tr> `

Comment: I have edited the code and updated the link to the new JSFiddle. Try the code and let me know if it works now.